# Should one use the singular or plural when the number is unknown?

Tags: idiom, grammar-choice, grammar-identification, grammarians

It just occurred to me (I'm that guy maybe starting the YouTube channel) that I don't know whether to use the singular or plural to address my audience in Latin.

My thinking goes like this: plural makes sense because (hopefully) my viewer base will be greater than one person. On the other hand, the singular makes sense because only one person at a time will be likely to watch my videos. On the other other hand, a group of people will probably watch my videos together.

So what do I use? The singular or the plural?

Comment: Oh, and let us know 5he channel when you start!

Answer (score 3):

This is a matter of choice of the author, no escape. However, I would suggest to refer to a plural audience, like a true Latin orator, like Cicero, who looked at the crowd of the *Senatus* with respect and yet authority, declaiming "*patres conscripti...*" before a stream of adorned, refined words exited his mouth.

Ok, probably you should choose another expression than *patres conscripti*, but remember you are always talking to a public audience, no matter how large or small it is. Manzoni, for example, wrote to his imaginary audience of "twenty readers", though he knew the readers  of his work would have been far more than twenty, and each an individual one.

It is useful at times to use the singular person to give emphasis  to the speech, or to make it more interesting, especially in examples and reasoning with the audience.